# How download multiples URL to local folder?

Tags: windows, download, url

I have multiples URLs and I would like a online site/ program  to download those files.

please help

Comment: Try asking at http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/ with more specifics.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using a download manager such as [DownThemAll](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/downthemall) (Firefox extension), wget (Linux command line), fatrat (Linux GUI), [InternetDownloadManager](http://www.internetdownloadmanager.com) (Windows GUI), or [VBDownloader](http://vbtools-developers.neocities.org) (Windows GUI, I am one of the developers).

My favourite for mass downloading of many small files is [DownThemAll](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/downthemall).

My favourite for downloading a few large files is [VBDownloader](http://vbtools-developers.neocities.org).

My favourite for Linux is fatrat.